# Non linear second order ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, asymptotics, nonlinear-system, perturbation-theory

I really need help solving this :

$$y_{xx}-\left(y^{3}-y\right)-\varepsilon\frac{1}{2}\left(1-y^{2}\right)=0
  $$
With boundary conditions :
$$ y(\pm \infty  )=-1 $$

I need to find a solution that is accurate up to $O(\epsilon)$
i all so know that
$$ y^{(k)}(\pm \infty) = 0\;\;\;\;\; for\; \; k>0 $$
Thanks alot!

Please note that holding boundary condition is not easy and very important, 
the answer given below is a great effort but unfortunatly it is not a good answer.
any help would be great!

Comment: Have you tried the regular perturbation expansion $v = v_0 + \epsilon v_1 + \epsilon^2 v_2 + \ldots$, where $v_i$ are functions of $x$, exclusively, and $v_0(\pm \infty) = -1$, $v_1(\pm \infty) = 1/4$, $v_i(\pm \infty ) = 0$ for $i \geq 2$? You only need to solve up to first order so $v \sim v_0 + \epsilon v_1$. I would love to elaborate some more on my comment, but I'm at an airport now!

Comment: @Dmoreno Thanks for you answer! 
But regular pertubations end up with the same answer of
eather a constant function or $\tanh[frac{x}{\sqrt{2}} $ Which does not keep boundary conditions.
Thus "making" me chosse the constant, but then next orders are constants too! 
and the numerical result of this is not a constant graph! 
it look a aliitle bit like a gaussian

Answer (score 3):

$$\frac{d^2v}{dx^2}-\left(v^{3}-v\right)-\varepsilon\frac{1}{2}\left(1-v^{2}\right)=0$$
This is an autonomous ODE. So, the change of function is :  $\frac{dv}{dx}=f(v)$

$\frac{d^2v}{dx^2}=\frac{df}{dv}\frac{dv}{dx}=f'f$

$$f'f-\left(v^{3}-v\right)-\varepsilon\frac{1}{2}\left(1-v^{2}\right)=0$$

$$\frac{1}{2}\frac{d(f^2)}{dv}=\left(v^{3}-v\right)+\varepsilon\frac{1}{2}\left(1-v^{2}\right)=0$$

$$f^2=\frac{1}{2}v^4-v^2+\varepsilon\left(v-\frac{1}{3}v^{3}\right)+c_1$$

$$\frac{dv}{dx}=\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}v^4-v^2+\varepsilon\left(v-\frac{1}{3}v^{3}\right)+c_1}$$

Especially in case of $\varepsilon=0$ with conditions  $v(\pm\infty)=-1$ and $v'(\pm\infty)=0$ :

$\frac{1}{2}(-1)^4-(-1)^2+c_1=0$ hense $c_1=\frac{1}{2}$

$$x=\int \frac{dv}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}v^4-v^2+\varepsilon\left(v-\frac{1}{3}v^{3}\right)+\frac{1}{2}}}+c_2$$

The exact analytical result is a very complicated formula involving an elliptic integral of the first kind. Further approximate calculus can be done in considering a series expansion relatively to $\varepsilon$, at least up to $O(\varepsilon^2)$.

We search an approximate on the form :
$$x=F_0(v)+\varepsilon F_1(v)+O(\varepsilon^2)$$

$$F_0(v)=\int \frac{dv}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}v^4-v^2+\frac{1}{2}}}+c_2=-\sqrt{2}\tanh^{-1}(v)+c_2$$

$$F_1(v)=\int\frac{\sqrt{2}v(v^2-3)}{3(v^2-1)^3}dv=-\frac{v^2-2}{6(v^2-1)^2}+c_3$$

Comment: @JJacuelin Thanks for you answer! 
 Can you explane how would you do a series expansion reltively to $\epsilon$ ? in which part would you recommend trying this? 
i dont need an analitic solution, just up to $ O(\epsilon)$

Comment: and by the way, i think the expression $ \varepsilon\left(v-\frac{2}{3}v^{3}\right) $ should be $ \varepsilon\left(v-\frac{1}{3}v^{3}\right) $

Comment: You are right, it is $\frac{1}{3}$. I corrected my first answer.

Comment: Your answer is wonderfull! 
But, im trying to get the inverse connection,
I cant seem to find a way of manipulating the $ \frac{dv}{dx} $
to get a $ O(\epsilon) $, can you think of something  ?

Comment: @ JJacquelin In addition, please notice that the arcTan(v) connection does not hold the boundary conditions...

Comment: An hint is added to my first answer about the method for series expansion (to be carefully verified, I didn't check it)

Comment: It is not arctan, but arctanh.

Comment: arctanh allso dosnt hold..

Comment: I answer only roughly, not with all details and not in considering all the cases. For example, it is up to you to consider the various cases of signs $\pm$ before the square roots.

Comment: why arctanh dosnt hold ?

Comment: boundary condition are : v(±∞)=−1
and $ arctanh(\pm 1)=\pm\infty $

Comment: boundary condition are : v(±∞)=−1 and $ arctanh(\pm 1)=\pm\infty $
JJacuelin, if you dont mind me bugging you, 
im sorry but i dont know what else to do, ive been working on this for the past week or so...
boundary condition are : v(±∞)=−1 and arctanh(±1)=±∞
which means bondary condition are not held... 
I think $ \epsilon $ should somehow apper in the the argument 
i am basiclly trying to find some solution that will be at the form of 
$ v(x)=-1+e^{\epsilon*x^{2}} $ all thuogh i dont know if this is the solution, ive plotted the graph with numerics and the resultwas that kind of shape

Comment: as for your comment about the pm, 
i was thinking of taking them both and stiching them together, but then my solution would not be differential at 0. which is pretty bad..

Comment: Case $\varepsilon=0$ and $x>0$ we got to $x=-\sqrt{2}\tanh^{-1}(v)$. hense $v=-\tanh\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}} \right)$. At limit $x=+\infty$ then $v(+\infty)=-\tanh(+\infty)=-1$. OK? . Case $x<0$ : different sign of the square roots, different function $x=+\sqrt{2}\tanh^{-1}(v)$

Comment: But you must realize that method of stiching the solutions means that ther is no derivative for x=0.
Dosnt that bother you? 
Shoudent bother me ?

Comment: What bother me is to continue such a discussion in this way. Good-bye !